# How do I get the current page name if it's not displayed in the URL when that page is the default page for a web app?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

I have an ASP.NET web site. There's an ASP.NET menu on the Masterpage. I want to to hide the menu if the current page is the login page. My login page is Login.aspx. Here's the code how I  make the menu invisible/visible:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if (pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("login.aspx") > 0)
    $('#mainmenu').hide();
else
    $('#mainmenu').show();
```

But when I deploy it on the IIS, the url does not include the page name when the web site is opened for the first time, thus the menu becomes visible.How do I determine the current page in this case?

Comment: Check for a element that only appears on the login page.

Comment: You are doing this in clientside. It's better to do it in server side. not using javascript

Comment: @CEbrus, that trick came to my mind too. But I find it a bit not smart

Comment: @ArashMilani, I've tried to do it on the server side before, that's what I too wanted at first.But the Menu is placed in the MasterPage. How do I control it? Wait a minute, maybe a Session variable? SOmething like a flag? I'll check it.

Comment: If the url doesn't change when on the login screen, your only options are to check the page's content, or to set a cookie.

Comment: @MikeJM Yeah hiding the menu when login session variable exists is the way to go. I also added an answer how to get it done in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it in server side IMO. anyway suppose your web app address is `http://yourdomain.com/app/` and your login page is the default page. then it will be displaied to user even if he is not typing `http://yourdomain.com/app/login.aspx` so all we need to check is that if our address is ending with `yourdomain.com/app/` or not. if so we will hide the menu.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var appDomainEndding = 'yourdomain.com/app/'
if (pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("login.aspx") > -1 || 
    pathname.indexOf(appDomainEndding, pathname.length - appDomainEndding.length) > -1)
$('#mainmenu').hide();
else
$('#mainmenu').show();
```

Comment: OP mentioned that the path doesn't change when the login page is displayed.

Comment: @Cerbrus He said "url does not include the page name when the web site is opened for the first time" I thinks he means when the default page of web app opens up there is no login.aspx on the url while the default page is the login page.

Comment: Exactly. So how is this code checking if the page is "login"?
If I understand you correctly, you are assuming that, if the user has logged in, the url has changed?

Comment: Thank you. This both answers my question and offers a better suggestion. I don't know why I did not think of having a session variable to decide for the visibility of the menu. I totally agree that a menu is something that should not be in the web browser even if it's not visible. If I hide it right on the server side then unauthenticated users won't anyhow know what menus the application has.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know what you mean. but it seems Mike just got one public page (login.aspx) that is also the webapp default page. other pages in his app are visible only for logged in users. and yes url does change while navigating to other pages. so all we need to do is check for 2 identical addresses. That's why this will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that in javascript, you can do that as below

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

// assuming the url as http://www.example.com
var url_length = pathArray.length;
//if url is http://www.example.com, then url_length will have 3
//if url is http://www.example.com/login.aspx, then url_length will have 4
```

So,

```
if( url_length==3 || pathArray[pathArray.length-1]=="login.aspx")
{
    $('#mainmenu').hide();
}
 else
 {
     $('#mainmenu').show();
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: OP mentioned that the path doesn't change when the login page is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If the url doesn't change when on the login screen, your only options are to check the page's content, or to set a cookie:
Make the server set something like a `"pageIsLogin=true"` cookie and check if `document.cookie` has that.

```
if(~document.cookie.indexOf("pageIsLogin=true")){
    //Login-specific settings here.
}else...
```

(Don't forget to unset that cookie on other pages)

Or, like my fist suggestion, check if the page contains a login-specific element:

```
if(document.getElementById("loginSpecificField")){
    //Login-specific settings here.
}else...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Supply a special variable on each "page"**. It's the classic go-to for this scenario. It is commonly used to allow a scripted, included menu system differentiate between any and all pages, and provide functionality on that basis such as highlighting, removing the link, etc. The way it works is to have a specific variable set on each page, which is then tested by the menu system and acted on accordingly.

The same variable can be reused for a variety of reasons, e.g. testing whether a specific function should be available, inclusion of page elements, etc.